# switch custom doesn't move and change using laravel ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have the following datatable :

[image]

I'm trying to update the status column :

So I'm using the following code :

My Controller :

```
function getdata(Request $request)
{
    if(request()->ajax())
    {
        return datatables()->of(Casting::latest()->get())
            ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                $button = '<table><tr><td>';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Modifier</button>';
                $button .= '</td><td>';
                $button .= '<div class="custom-switch custom-switch-secondary-inverse mb-2 custom-switch-small">';
                        $button .= '<input type="checkbox" data-id="'.$data->id.'" name="status" class="custom-switch-input"';
                if ($data->status == 1) {
                    $button .= 'checked';
                }
                $button .= '><label class="custom-switch-btn" for="switchS4"></label></div>';
                $button .= '</td></tr></table>';
                return $button;
        })
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->make(true);
    }
    return view('Casting.castingss');
}
```

My Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#datatableRows').DataTable({
  processing: true,
  serverSide: true,
  ajax:{
   url: "{{ route('castingss.getdata') }}",
  },
  columns:[
  
   {
    data: 'casting_photo',
    name: 'casting_photo',
    render: function(data, type, full, meta){
              return "<img src={{ URL::to('/') }}/castingimages/" + data +  " class='list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left' />";
    },
    orderable: false
   },
   {data:'casting_name',
    name: 'casting_name',
    render:function(data,type,full,meta){
      return "<a href='profile'>" + data + "</a>";
    }
   },
    {
    data: 'casting_cin',
    name: 'casting_cin'
   },
    {
    data: 'casting_phone',
    name: 'casting_phone'
   },
   
   {
    data: 'action',
    name: 'action',
    orderable: false
   }
  ]
 });

 });
</script>
```

The switch custom doesn't change and doesn't move.

I want when clicking on switch custom change the status in the database

I used this script to check if the switch custom works :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.custom-switch-input').change(function () {
     alert('I am here');
});
```

});

But nothing happens
How can I do that?

Comment: What CSS library are you using to make the slider checkbox?

Comment: emm , I don't know, I'm using  a template that contains this component

Comment: What is the template?

Comment: Dore-JQuery-Admin-Dashoboard

Comment: It's not open source, so I'm afraid I'm a bit out of ideas. So to confirm, without the jQuery, are you able to switch the custom switch?

Comment: No I'm not able

Comment: This is not a JavaScript or Laravel issue. This is a HTML/CSS issue. Ensure that the template HTML matches the documentation for the template you are using and you are including the same CSS used by the template.